# SQLite: how to find a subString between specific strings in all rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with lot of rows. how can i extract a string from all rows that between specific strings. for example i have this text: "stack**over**flow". the strings "stack" and "flow" is common in all rows; how can i extract string between in this tow String and copy to a new column?
what i try is:

```
UPDATE word set m = (SELECT m FROM word WHERE m BETWEEN 'stack' and 'flow') ;
```

Update:
consider this text:"I like stackoverflow services."
the words "stack" and "flow" is common in all rows and I want string between them.

Comment: You can ONLY use nested queries when they return a single value, hence this won't work. You should instead either use https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp or `JOIN`

Comment: You can use `substr(x,y)` to get the word in between, where `m like 'stack%' and m like '%flow'`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
//tested string 'here is something like that'
update word set m=(select substr(m,instr(m,'is'),instr(m,'like')-1) from word);
//ouput will be 'is something like'
```

this is pure mathematics using string function of mysql

Answer (score 0):

Use `substr` to get the word start from 6th character (stack) and then how many character you want to take. The length - 9 is mean total word length deduct length of 'stack' and 'flow'

`UPDATE word set m = (substr(m, 6, length(m)-9)) where m like 'stack%' and m like '%flow'`

Comment: thanks u but the length of string in rows is different.

Comment: @HadiAhmadi uh then what kind of string you expected?

Comment: for example my text in row is "I like stackoverflow !.....". the words "stack" and "flow" is common in all rows and i want string between them.

Comment: @HadiAhmadi sorry for late reply, but i think answer from AK47 is much more easier

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
UPDATE word 
set m = replace(replace(m,'stack',''),'flow','')
where m like 'stack%' and m like '%flow';
```